# Assign Gridview values to text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid

I have to ask about A question in C#,Asp.net... i created 3 textbox for empid, name and Address

If i Click the "**Edit Button**" with manually type empid in a text box. i want to assign other two values name & Address to  their textbox. then after i use update button to update

Can anyone teach me with code?

```
//Asp.net 

 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Empid" Width="50px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name" Width="50px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Address" Width="50px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />

</div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="update " />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Edit" Width="61px" />
</form>



 //Cs for update button 


    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=s\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial catalog = sample;Integrated security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE empdetails SET Name='" + TextBox2.Text + "',Address='" + TextBox3.Text + "' WHERE Empid ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Empdetails";
    GridView.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView.DataBind();
    TextBox1.Text = "";
    TextBox2.Text = "";
    TextBox3.Text = "";
    conn.Close();
```

I code like this ,if i **Edit Button**,  with entered Empid, i want other values name & Address  ll  assign to text box

Comment: Ha ha LOL , show us what you have tried :D

Comment: Please post some code what you have tried.

Comment: By ajax call send empid to server page , get data  name & Address  from server and on success of it display it.

Comment: Amarnath Are u a genius ? stop kiddin

Comment: Thank you for ur replay Shreyas , i added code here as per ur comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps:**

1. Get the Employee details in GridView.

   ```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       GetEmpDetails()
   End Sub
   Private Sub GetEmpDetails()
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=s\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial catalog = sample;Integrated security=True");

   conn.Open();

   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Empdetails";
   GridView.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   GridView.DataBind();
   End Sub
   ```
2. Add this Property `AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"` to the gridview in the design page.

   ```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
             AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
             CellPadding="4" >
   </asp:GridView>
   ```
3. On the SelectedIndexChanged of the Grid get the RowIndex so that we will get the row value of the row selected.

   ```
   Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
       LoadValues(GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex)
   End Sub
   ```
4. Then Load the grid values to the respective textbox.
5. And change the values you want but don't change the ID (Highly recommended)
6. Then Click UpdateButton. Call Update Query there.
7. Load grid value again and bind it. So that you can see the change instantly.

Happy Coding..!! :)

Comment: Thank u for ur reply,I didnt use Checkbox here

Comment: @BAP i too have not mentioned checkbox..!!

Comment: @BAP You want this process right?? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: :) k wat do you want to achieve now?? tel me how can i help you?

Comment: now i edited  the question , check pls.  i added one more button for edit.. if i click edit button with empid ,i want to assign other 2 values in the textbox

Comment: ok in the edit button pass the empid and use select query along with the where condition of the empid. fetch the value from the database and you will be getting a dataset with a single row as you have mentioned the Id. Pass the row values to the textboxes..!! :)

Comment: ok i ll  use checkbox tool can u send c# code to pass n assign row to it

Comment: Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    LoadValues(GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex)
End Sub                                                                                                                                                                Convert this to C#

Comment: protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 LoadValues(GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex);
} You can use this **[TOOL](http://converter.telerik.com/)** for converting  C# to Vb and vice versa